# Coroutines "Asynchronous withTimeout" official tutorial strange behavior

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the official guide "[Cancellation and timeouts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html)" section "[Asynchronous timeout and resources](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#asynchronous-timeout-and-resources)﻿" there is an example that is supposed to... "If you run the above code you'll see that it does not always print zero, though it may depend on the timings of your machine you may need to tweak timeouts in this example to actually see non-zero values."

```
var acquired = 0

class Resource {
    init { acquired++ } // Acquire the resource
    fun close() { acquired-- } // Release the resource
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        repeat(100_000) { // Launch 100K coroutines
            launch { 
                val resource = withTimeout(60) { // Timeout of 60 ms
                    delay(50) // Delay for 50 ms
                    Resource() // Acquire a resource and return it from withTimeout block     
                }
                resource.close() // Release the resource
            }
        }
    }
    // Outside of runBlocking all coroutines have completed
    println(acquired) // Print the number of resources still acquired
}
```

I do not understand how that work.
If we let the timeout to 60, instances of Resource are never created. We had to go up to 120 to see instances been created.
However 60ms looks enough to let include a delay(50) + an instance creation. No?

Does someone could explain that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you verify that any instance was not created?

Comment: @mightyWOZ Adding a static (compagnon object var) to store count through Ressource init

Answer (score 1):

You should not assume these timings are accurate. `delay(50)` waits for about 50ms and `withTimeout(60)` timeouts after about 60ms. I believe both of them gives "at least" guarantee, but they may have to wait practically indefinitely. `delay()` may wait for a longer time than expected, because there are no free threads to resume. `withTimeout()` may timeout after a longer time, because coroutine does not cooperate for cancelling.

In your case it is possible that it takes more than 50ms for all 100_000 coroutines to get to `delay()` point. In that case they aren't resumed after 50ms, because they still wait for the thread to become free to handle them. But this is just a guess. Try to replace it with e.g. `delay(150)` and `withTimeout(160)`.

The main point of this example is that if the timeout happens after the delay has resumed, but before the end of `withTimeout()` block then exiting from `withTimeout()` will throw `CancellationException`. As a result, `Resource()` will be invoked, but `resource.close()` won't.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation (and your time) but I don't understand, in that case what it means: withTimeout.

I did some additional tests, measuring the effective time of delay() and withTimeout().

When the algo is not able to go though and throws a "CancellationException" with a param of 60 ms, the time out is about of 550 ms. And when the algo go through up to .close(), needing a param of 300 ms, the time out is about 640 ms.

I can understand delay() waiting at least for the given value, but a TimeOut is TimeOut, the normal warranty is maximum the given time.

No?

Comment: Well, no :-) There are two reasons. First, even cancellation requires some thread to handle it. Imagine that all these 100k coroutines are waiting at `delay()` and then all of them are cancelled at once. We need to throw 100k exceptions, but we have only one thread, so we need to do it sequentially. Second, cancellations are cooperative. That means `withTimeout()` only flags the coroutine as cancelled and the code running in the coroutine needs to intentionally check whether it was cancelled. For example: `withTimeout(500) { Thread.sleep(1000) }` takes about 1000ms to cancel, not 500ms.

Comment: Thanks again. What I must retain is that it's fully COOPERATIVE so each code block must take care to not go over its own "incompatible state of running". Something like that...
As in example I early saw in the tuto where code block must check its cancelled status given by x.cancel() to let quit it "by hand".
Coming from Threading it's a bit ... weird.

Comment: Why is it weird when coming from threads? They're exactly the same. Try to `interrupt()` the thread that performs some calculations and you will see it also won't stop. When performing long calculations you should check `Thread.interrupted()` periodically, similarly as in coroutines, because otherwise your code can't be stopped.

Comment: You're right. I was stuck on pthread that preemptively cancels. After verification C++, Java, Swift and Kt have cooperative cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why instance have no chance to be created is that execution of delay(50) and more generally the whole task take lot of time because 100_000 coroutines competing on the same thread don't let much time to execute in the delay.

So reducing the number of created coroutines to 10 or 100 (a more realistic situation), tasks look to complete quickly, respecting time and timeout.

Here's results

```
Number of  | Created   | Still     |
coroutines | Resource  | Opened    |
           | instances | Resources |
-----------+-----------+-----------+
 100_000   |       0   |      -    |
  10_000   |    8588   |    635    |
   1_000   |    1000   |      0    |
     100   |     100   |      0    |
```